# Bootstrap 4 custom grid

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, grid

How to perform the following grid using **Bootstrap 4**?

I want one column to be from the edge of the window to the inside and the other one as half as standard .container?

[image: bootstrap 4 grid]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `fluid-container`, not `container` because two of your `columns` exceeds the `container`. But `column` can not do so in `Bootstrap`.

If `fluid-container` is too big, restrict its width with custom CSS.

```css
.row div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.h-200px {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 mx-auto p-4 bg-dark">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 bg-success h-200px  ">

    </div>
    <div class="col-3 offset-3 mr-auto ml-0 bg-primary h-200px  ">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 mx-auto p-4 bg-dark">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 offset-3 ml-auto mr-0 bg-success h-200px  ">

    </div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-primary h-200px  ">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 mx-auto p-4 bg-dark">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Check [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pVpbvq)

Comment: That could be but this layout is not equal to a regular container [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NMXrom)

Comment: @user2865895 The container in the img is not equal to the container in the link neither.  You need to add more info too.